# Python | Tkinter | TkCalendar : how to customize 'DateEntry Date Picker' object? like increasing Width, and more?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, datepicker, tkinter-entry, tkcalendar

I'm developing a simple Python stand-alone application, that uses a GUI datePicker, and I went for using **'from tkcalendar import DateEntry'**. | using python 2.7 (for older windows PC)

while using 'DateEntry - Date Picker', I not able to find a few major things, even the **documentation** doesn't explain on this. I went through these:

1. https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#
2. https://tkdocs.com/shipman/
3. https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-DateEntry.php

I'm looking ways to

1. Change width of Widget
2. open widget on click of entry/input bar (not only drop-down arrow)

Code Ex:     [image]

```
DateEntry(window, date_pattern='yyyy-MM-dd', width= 67, background=CONST.TITLE_BG_COLOR, bad=2)
```

Any suggestion, references and even alternative are appreciated. Thanks.